# Why is an image, which read from a folder with 'anydpi' qualifier, blurry in the emulator?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-jetpack-compose

I have two identical images which have slightly different names and located in different folders:

[image]

Also i have one small activity with the following code:

```
package com.test.composetraining

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.Image
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Row
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Spacer
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.height
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.size
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.width
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.res.painterResource
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp

data class Message(val author: String, val body: String)

@Composable
fun MessageCard(msg: Message){
    Row(modifier = Modifier.padding(all = 8.dp)) {
        Image(
            painter = painterResource(R.drawable.profile_picture),
            contentDescription = "Contact profile picture",
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(200.dp)
//                .clip(CircleShape)
        )

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(8.dp))

        Column {
            Text(text = msg.author)
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(4.dp))
            Text(text = msg.body)
        }
    }
}

@Preview
@Composable
fun PreviewMessageCard(){
    MessageCard(Message("Android", "Jetpack Compose"))
}

class MainActivity:  ComponentActivity(){
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent{
            MessageCard(Message("Android", "Jetpack Compose"))
        }
    }
}
```

When i run this app, i get the following result:

[image]

But if i change `painter = painterResource(R.drawable.profile_picture)` to `painter = painterResource(R.drawable.profile_picture2)` then i get this:

[image]

**Why does it happen ?**